# Sum of columns with same name in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, sum

I have a table with a structure like this:

```
op | name | amount | total |
1  |   a  |   40   |   2   | 
2  |   a  |   80   |   4   | 
5  |   b  |   30   |   5   | 
6  |   b  |   50   |   7   | 
1  |   c  |   20   |   1   | 
3  |   c  |   30   |   4   |
```

I want the `amount` and `total` columns to be added according to the `name` column (I need the `op` column to keep appearing). For this example, my select would return this result:

```
op | name | amount | total |
1  |   a  |  120   |   6   | 
2  |   a  |  120   |   6   | 
5  |   b  |  80    |   12  | 
6  |   b  |  80    |   12  | 
1  |   c  |  50    |   5   | 
3  |   c  |  50    |   5   |
```

Can I do this using PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create schema:

```
create table tab (
  op integer,
  name varchar,
  amount integer,
  total integer
);

insert into tab values 
(1,'a',40,2), 
(2,'a',80,4), 
(5,'b',30,5), 
(6,'b',50,7), 
(1,'c',20,1), 
(3,'c',30,4);
```

`SELECT`statement:

```
    select t1.op, t1.name, t2.amount, t2.total 
      from tab t1
inner join  (select name,
                    sum(amount) as amount, 
                    sum(total) as total 
               from tab 
           group by name) t2
        on t1.name = t2.name
```

Result:

| op | name | amount | total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 120 | 6 |
| 2 | a | 120 | 6 |
| 5 | b | 80 | 12 |
| 6 | b | 80 | 12 |
| 1 | c | 50 | 5 |
| 3 | c | 50 | 5 |

Test it here:
[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=0d0eb41e8700c1268e27d6d585c13a1b)

Comment: Thank u very much :D

Answer (score 2):

You can use window function `SUM() OVER` for that

> ```
> CREATE TABLE tab1 (
>   "op" INTEGER,
>   "name" VARCHAR(1),
>   "amount" INTEGER,
>   "total" INTEGER
> );
>
> INSERT INTO tab1
>   ("op", "name", "amount", "total")
> VALUES
>   ('1', 'a', '40', '2'),
>   ('2', 'a', '80', '4'),
>   ('5', 'b', '30', '5'),
>   ('6', 'b', '50', '7'),
>   ('1', 'c', '20', '1'),
>   ('3', 'c', '30', '4');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT 
> "op"
> , "name", SUM("amount") OVER (PARTITION BY "name") as "amount"
> , SUM("total") OVER (PARTITION BY "name") as "total"
> FROM tab1
> ```
>
> ```
> op | name | amount | total
> -: | :--- | -----: | ----:
>  1 | a    |    120 |     6
>  2 | a    |    120 |     6
>  5 | b    |     80 |    12
>  6 | b    |     80 |    12
>  1 | c    |     50 |     5
>  3 | c    |     50 |     5
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=ab168f95399af7d8f20074e57a242169)*

Comment: Brilliant idea! the problem is that I cannot use windowing where I am running the query :/ thanks!